# how to sort a string array by number value style?

Tags: c#

I have a string array, I want to sort it by number, please give to me a solution.
Example:

Original array: [Item 1, Item 3, Item 2, Item 4]

Sorted array: [Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4]

```
private string sortString(string strToken)
{
    char[] arrToken = strToken.ToCharArray();
    Array.Sort(arrToken);
    return new string(arrToken);
}
```

Comment: Extract the number, parse it to an int, sort with it. Have you tried anything? If yes, post the code .

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *sort*, just `Sort()`:

```
  String[] source = new String[] {
    "Item 1", 
    "Item 3", 
    "Item 2", 
    "Item 4"
  };

  Array.Sort<String>(source, (Comparison<String>) (
      (left, right) => {
        //TODO: Extract the actual value here
        int leftValue = int.Parse(left.Substring(left.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
        int rightValue = int.Parse(right.Substring(right.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1));

        return leftValue.CompareTo(rightValue);
      }
    ));
```

To print out

```
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, source));
```

The outcome is

```
  Item 1
  Item 2
  Item 3
  Item 4
```